# check-in binary files in git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am unable to push the binary files like .exe and .dll files in bitbucket server(remote). We need to push these files to remote as per our requirement,but pushing the binaries is not allowed. Is there any way we can push these binaries to bitbucket server?

Error:
The commit contains a file type associated with binaries which are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change the server-side policy that is preventing this.

Comment: Specifically, Bitbucket Server does not ship such a capability by default, so an administrator would have set this up.

Comment: ... I imagine they have good reason too. While you could push binaries (especially now that we have Git LFS) there's often a better way. .exe and .dll files are software outputs, not inputs so rather than using an SCM like Git you might consider dedicated artefact management.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Bitbucket issue. You need to talk to the Bitbucket administrators to understand the server policy and to know if there's something you/they can do about this.